# Getting "Variable not in scope: w :: Integer" error while defining the type of "w"

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm a new to Haskell, and learning list comprehensions.From what I have seen from the examples, I'm trying to execute the following code in

```
[ w :: Integer | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..10], z <- [1..10], w == x*2 + y*2 + z*2, w < 20]
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> :66:3: error: Variable not in scope: w :: Integer
>
> :66:60: error: Variable not in scope: w :: Integer
>
> :66:82: error: Variable not in scope: w :: Integer

I have searched the cause of the problem, and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478551/haskell-not-in-scope-list-comprehension) question, the problem seems that Haskell does not know the type of the variable, but in my code, I'm defining it (as we do while we are doing math), but still the problems occurs, so what is wrong with this kind of definition and how can we solve it ?

Note that, the whole purpose of trying to execute this piece of code is just to learn how can I do list comprehension by using the same notation as I use in mathematics.

Comment: `w == x*2 + y*2 + z*2` doesn't define `w`, but sets up an equality check involving an (undefined) `w`. You mean `let w = x*2 + y*2 + z*2` instead. (Though if your intended formula is the Pythagoras one, you actually mean `let w = x^2 + y^2 + z^2`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition `w == x*2 + ...` checks whether an *already defined* variable `w` is equal to `x*2 + ...`. If you want to define `w` there, you need `let w = x*2 + ...` instead.

```
[ w :: Integer 
| x <- [1..10], y <- [1..10], z <- [1..10], let w = x*2 + y*2 + z*2, w < 20]
```

GHCi demo:

```
> [ w :: Integer | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..10], z <- [1..10], let w = x*2 + y*2 + z*2, w < 20]
[6,8,10,12,14,16,18,8,10,12,14,16,18,10,12,14,16,18,12,14,16,18,14,16,18,16,18,18,8,10,12,14,16,18,10,12,14,16,18,12,14,16,18,14,16,18,16,18,18,10,12,14,16,18,12,14,16,18,14,16,18,16,18,18,12,14,16,18,14,16,18,16,18,18,14,16,18,16,18,18,16,18,18,18]
```

Comment: There is some problematics comma somewhere

Comment: @onurcanbektas I just tried to copy & paste the above into GHCi, and I can see no errors. Keep it on a single line, if you have indentation errors (or indent the second line more).

Comment: Ok, apparently, I was putting an extra "=". Thanks a lot for the answer.